# How to provide null data in dataprovider in Testng

Tags: testng, dataprovider

I'm facing a scenario where you need to pass username, password and OTP....

I used data provider to pass this three data and the challenge which i face is for the first time when the username is wrong and when you click on submit it doesn't show up the OTP box, so i need to provide a null value for the first time and how can I do that?

Comment: Did you checked manually where if no text is provided in username and when clicked on `submit` button, does the OTP box appears?

Also, for testing with `null` args on input text fields, please use apis to test out those scenarios preferably.

Comment: Hii Bipin, solved my issue...i did send my value as null but used a condition based upon the error message that pops up, so the process didn't fail.